# Laravel 7.x Route Pagination / Friendly URL

Tags: laravel, pagination, routes, friendly-url, laravel-7

Hello everyone recently i started a project on Laravel **7.x** but i have some problems.

I made a search with laravel default pagination.

This is my code:

**Search form**

```
<form action="/search" method="GET">            
    <input type="text" name="k" id="k" value="" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_search(Request $request)
    {

        $keyword = request('k');

        $data = DB::table('posts')
                    ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%$keyword%')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(20);


        return view('search', ['data' => $data]);
```

**Route**

`Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'MainController@get_search', 'as' => 'search']);`

**View**

```
@foreach($data as $item)

        {{ $item->title }}

@endforeach

       {{ $data->links() }}
```

So i'm getting url like `/search?key=keyword&page=2`

All i want is to make looks like `/search/keyword/page/2/`

Thanks!

Comment: @A.ANoman ```str_replace``` function where?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `->paginate(20)`

by `->paginate(20, ['*'], 'page', $page)`

It's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you modify the **routes/web.php** file. Use route arguments

```
 Route::get('/search/{keyword}/page/{page}', 'SearchController@index')->name('.search');
```

And then, on the controller,

```
public function index($keyword, $page){ //Receive parameters
   $data = DB::table('posts')
      ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%$keyword%')
      ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
      ->paginate(20);
   return view('search', ['data' => $data]);
...
}
```

Comment: The route works, but the page it isn't changed. it takes by default only the page 1. Results are only those from page 1 and also the pagination remains active on 1. So basically it doesn't take the page.

Comment: The form action must be modified. You did it? Also make sure to add the collect(['data' => $data]) method when passing parameters to a view

Comment: No, i didn't. My form is 

 <form action="/search" method="GET">            
    <input type="text" name="k" id="k" value="" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form> 

 add the collect(['data' => $data]) well isn't added into view?
 
@foreach($data as $item)

        {{ $item->title }}

@endforeach

       {{ $data->links() }}

Comment: Probably my problem it's on view atm. I get the links paginations like 

/search/keyword/page/2?page=2 ... etc

Comment: The form just sends the data. In your case, using the GET method using the URL parameters (?keyword="x"). To redirect them to the "/page/.../" format you, need to edit them as i did

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i made what did u said above and when getting `print_r($data)` on search blade i am getting this

```
Array
(
    [current_page] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 3
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 4
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 5
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 6
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 7
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 8
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 9
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => keyword 10
                )

        )

    [first_page_url] => hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword?page=1
    [from] => 1
    [last_page] => 5
    [last_page_url] => hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword?page=5
    [next_page_url] => hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword?page=2
    [path] => hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword
    [per_page] => 10
    [prev_page_url] => 
    [to] => 10
    [total] => 49
)
```

Shows the same results while i am replacing the url `hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword/page/2/`

Any URL outputs the same result, it's just changed the ?page=x, but the results are the same. basically the `hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword/page/`**2**/ does nothing.

- The results are changing only if i change the url to `hxxp://xxxx.xxx/search/keyword/page/2/`**?page=2** which i don't need to..